# Benefits of Inversion Control

Tags: spring

In spring what are the benefits we can get when using **inversion of control** to create object?
And Why should we use **inversion of control**?

Answer (score 0):

Without Spring you have to create every object on your own by calling the constructors.
With Spring it is done by Spring framework for you.

So your application has a lot of connection between all objects it needs to do its job. Depending on the size of your application this *object-network* can get very complex and hard to manage. Inversion of control means that a framework (like Spring) is managing this *object-network* instead of you / the programmer.

Now it depends on the size, type and complexity of your application, how much it benefits from a framework and inversion of control principle.
In my German blog I describe Spring basics and the Spring IoC container with more details:
https://agile-coding.blogspot.com/2020/10/kernkonzepte-von-spring-beans-und.html

Comment: Thank u. This was helpful for me.